# Flextable error when using gg_chunk(): Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, flextable

I am trying to use `flextable` to produce a table with ggplots inside cells using `gg_chunk()` however I keep getting an error: Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable even if I try to run the code from `rmarkdown` using an `officeodown` template.

This is the code I am using:

```
  library(flextable)
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
  
  df <-
    iris %>% select(Species, Petal.Width) %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest(data = c(Petal.Width))
  
  gg <- function(x) {
    d <- x %>% mutate(x = row_number()) %>% rename(y = 1)
    p <- ggplot(d) +
      geom_line(aes(x, y)) +
      theme_void()
    list(p)
  }
  
  df_gg <- df %>% mutate(gg = map(data, ~ gg(.x)))
  
  ft <- flextable(data = df_gg) %>%
    compose(j = "gg", value = as_paragraph(gg_chunk(
      value = gg,
      width = 1.5,
      height = .4
    ))) %>%
    autofit()
  ft
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: gg is a function, not a ggplot object

Comment: @DavidGohel Thanks - yes it was dumb of me to use the same name for the function and column. Now when I change the column name to gg_p (and also j and value) I get ``Error in gg_chunk(value = gg_p, width = 1.5, height = 0.4) : 
  object 'gg_p' not found
``

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the piping. When I use 
  `ft <- flextable(df_gg)`
 `ft <- mk_par(ft, j = "gg_p", value = as_paragraph(gg_chunk(value = gg_p, width = 1.5, height = 0.4)))`
It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's an issue with purrr::compose and flextable::compose.

This should work:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

df <-
  iris %>% select(Species, Petal.Width) %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest(data = c(Petal.Width))

gg <- function(x) {
  d <- x %>% mutate(x = row_number()) %>% rename(y = 1)
  p <- ggplot(d) +
    geom_line(aes(x, y)) +
    theme_void()
  list(p)
}

df_gg <- df %>% mutate(gg = map(data, ~ gg(.x)))

ft <- flextable(data = df_gg) %>%
  compose(j = "gg", value = as_paragraph(gg_chunk(
    value = gg,
    width = 1.5,
    height = .4
  ))) %>%
  autofit()
ft
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have another question for you (if you have time) on iterating the compose step over multiple columns but I'll post separately.